# Как инициализировать строковый массив в конструкторе класса?

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть класс, приватным образом объявляется массив строк:

```
class Class
{
    private:
        char adress[4][30];
        ...
};
```

а в конструкторе происходит инициализация:

```
...
    public:
        Class()
        {
         ...
         adress[4][30] = {"D:\\New Folder\\Test\\animals.txt",
              "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\plant.txt",
              "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\hobby.txt",
              "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\color.txt"
                 };
         ...
        }

...
```

Компилятор ругается:

```
IntelliSense: требуется выражение
```

и указывает на открывающуюся фигурную скобочку массива.
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy( address[0], "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\animals.txt" );
strcpy( address[1], "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\plant.txt" );
strcpy( address[2], "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\hobby.txt" );
strcpy( address[3], "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\color.txt" );
```

Это если не заморачиваться переполнением. Но зачем тут вообще `char[][]`, если это C++?

```
using namespace std;

vector <string> address;

//address.push_back("D:\\New Folder\\Test\\animals.txt");
//address.push_back("D:\\New Folder\\Test\\plant.txt");
//address.push_back("D:\\New Folder\\Test\\hobby.txt");
//address.push_back("D:\\New Folder\\Test\\color.txt");

address[0] = "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\animals.txt";    
address[1] = "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\plant.txt";    
address[2] = "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\hobby.txt";    
address[3] = "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\color.txt";
```

Comment: потому как по-иному не умею ) 
спасибо за подсказку )

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: ушел читать MSDN =)

спс за науку

Comment: @LivAlex, еще вариант, например, так:

    const static char templ_addr[4][30] = {"D:\\New Folder\\Test\\animals.txt",
        "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\plant.txt",
        ....
        };
        ....
    
а в конструкторе

      ....
      public:
        Class()
        {
         ...
         memcpy(adress, templ_addr, sizeof(templ_addr));
         ...

Компилятор сделал бы так же, если бы понимал Ваши намерения.

Comment: @avp: http://ideone.com/XCQKdZ

Comment: @VladD, и начальный вариант TC

    char adress[4][30] = { ... };

можно так же инициализировать?

А если таких "adress" десяток?

Comment: @avp: вы имеете в виду это: http://ideone.com/SunavO ? Присваивать с таким синтаксисом ЕМНИМС нельзя, инициализировать можно.

Comment: @VladD, да, именно инициализировать. Что присваивать нельзя - это очевидно. 

А в общем, надо просто "учить  матчасть" (т.е. все языковые конструкции С++). Это я о себе.

Comment: @avp: C++11 — это, с синтаксической точки зрения, совершенно новый язык. Так что учить матчасть надо всем.

Answer (score 1):

в .cpp сделать

```
const char *templ_addr[] = {
  "str1",
  "str2",
  "str3",
  "str4"
};
```

если эти строки изменять не надо то работайте прямо с templ_addr, иначе в классике сделать

```
private:
    std::string adress[4];
```

а в конструкторе (в .cpp)

```
Class::Class()
{
    adress[0] = templ_addr[0];
    adress[1] = templ_addr[1];
    adress[2] = templ_addr[2];
    adress[3] = templ_addr[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(выношу из обсуждения в комментариях)

В C++11 можно [так](http://ideone.com/SunavO):

```
Class() :
    adress
    {
        "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\animals.txt",
        "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\plant.txt",
        "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\hobby.txt",
        "D:\\New Folder\\Test\\color.txt"
    }
{
    // тут конструктор
}
```

А вообще-то, как вам правильно подсказывают, если пишете на C++, используйте `std::vector<std::string>`. Синтаксис инициализации [такой же](http://ideone.com/XCQKdZ).